# Combine two queries to one

Tags: mysql

> I need to write query that finds the average for each classname, total average for each student, I already wrote two separate query for each one of those, but how to combine to one query?

My 1st query:

```
select distinct  StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, ClassName, avg(Grade) as 'average for this subject'
from tests 
inner join students on tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
group by StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName;
```

My 2nd query:

```
select distinct  StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, avg(Grade) as 'total average'
from tests 
inner join students on tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
group by StudentFirstName,StudentLastName;
```

**Students table:**

```
  pk-INT           VARCHAR             VARCHAR
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| StudentID | StudentFirstName | StudentLastName |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
|         1 | agam             | rafaeli         |
|         2 | amir             | aizinger        |
|         3 | avi              | caspi           |
|         4 | avia             | wolf            |
|         5 | ben              | moskovich       |
|         6 | chen             | segalovich      |
|         7 | dana             | levy            |
|         8 | daniel           | marcus          |
|         9 | daphna           | chwarts         |
|        10 | david            | cohen           |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

**Tests table:**

```
  PK-VARCHR    PK-VARCHR     PK&FK-INT   INT
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| TestDate   | ClassName  | StudentID | Grade |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2017-07-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    88 |
| 2017-08-02 | Algo       |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    80 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Set-theory |         1 |    85 |
| 2017-09-04 | Calcules   |         1 |    86 |
| 2016-05-03 | Set-theory |         2 |    84 |
| 2016-07-02 | Calcules   |         2 |    89 |
| 2016-07-04 | Algo       |         2 |    83 |
| 2016-07-05 | Algebra    |         2 |    79 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         3 |    99 |
| 2016-07-02 | Algo       |         3 |    97 |
| 2016-07-03 | Calcules   |         3 |    96 |
| 2016-09-03 | Set-theory |         3 |    95 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         4 |    78 |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: You should specify which RDBMS you're working in, what you expect the final result to look like, and if this is homework its good to mention that too. Posting the table sample as `CREATE` statements is also helpful so people can quickly test their queries on your data set - [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is great for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for can be done with one query using `WITH ROLLUP`

## PROPOSED QUERY

```
SELECT BB.StudentFirstName,BB.StudentLastName,
IFNULL(AA.ClassName,
CONCAT('All Classes for ',BB.StudentFirstName,' ',BB.StudentLastName)) ClassName,
AA.StudentAverage FROM
(select A.StudentID,A.ClassName,avg(Grade) StudentAverage
from tests A inner join students B on A.StudentID=B.StudentID
group by A.StudentID,A.ClassName WITH ROLLUP) AA
inner join students BB on AA.StudentID=BB.StudentID;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS error404;
CREATE DATABASE error404;
USE error404
CREATE TABLE students
(
    StudentID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    StudentFirstName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentLastName  VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);
INSERT INTO students (StudentFirstName,StudentLastName) VALUES
('agam'  , 'rafaeli'), ('amir'  , 'aizinger'), ('avi'   , 'caspi'),
('avia'  , 'wolf '), ('ben'   , 'moskovich'), ('chen'  , 'segalovich'),
('dana'  , 'levy '), ('daniel', 'marcus'), ('daphna', 'chwarts');
CREATE TABLE tests
(
    testid    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TestDate  DATE,
    ClassName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    Grade     INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (testid),
    KEY (StudentID)
);
INSERT INTO tests (TestDate,ClassName,StudentID,Grade) VALUES
('2017-07-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 88 ), ('2017-08-02', 'Algo'       , 1 , 97 ),
('2017-09-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 80 ), ('2017-09-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 97 ),
('2017-09-01', 'Set-theory' , 1 , 85 ), ('2017-09-04', 'Calcules'   , 1 , 86 ),
('2016-05-03', 'Set-theory' , 2 , 84 ), ('2016-07-02', 'Calcules'   , 2 , 89 ),
('2016-07-04', 'Algo'       , 2 , 83 ), ('2016-07-05', 'Algebra'    , 2 , 79 ),
('2016-06-03', 'Algebra'    , 3 , 99 ), ('2016-07-02', 'Algo'       , 3 , 97 ),
('2016-07-03', 'Calcules'   , 3 , 96 ), ('2016-09-03', 'Set-theory' , 3 , 95 ),
('2016-06-03', 'Algebra'    , 4 , 78 );
```

## PROPOSED QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT BB.StudentFirstName,BB.StudentLastName,
    -> IFNULL(AA.ClassName,
    -> CONCAT('All Classes for ',BB.StudentFirstName,' ',BB.StudentLastName)) ClassName,
    -> AA.StudentAverage FROM
    -> (select A.StudentID,A.ClassName,avg(Grade) StudentAverage
    -> from tests A inner join students B on A.StudentID=B.StudentID
    -> group by A.StudentID,A.ClassName WITH ROLLUP) AA
    -> inner join students BB on AA.StudentID=BB.StudentID;
+------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+----------------+
| StudentFirstName | StudentLastName | ClassName                     | StudentAverage |
+------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+----------------+
| agam             | rafaeli         | Algebra                       |        88.3333 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Algo                          |        97.0000 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Calcules                      |        86.0000 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Set-theory                    |        85.0000 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | All Classes for agam rafaeli  |        88.8333 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Algebra                       |        79.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Algo                          |        83.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Calcules                      |        89.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Set-theory                    |        84.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | All Classes for amir aizinger |        83.7500 |
| avi              | caspi           | Algebra                       |        99.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Algo                          |        97.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Calcules                      |        96.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Set-theory                    |        95.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | All Classes for avi caspi     |        96.7500 |
| avia             | wolf            | Algebra                       |        78.0000 |
| avia             | wolf            | All Classes for avia wolf     |        78.0000 |
+------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## BONUS QUERY

This query includes all students whether they took a class or not

```
SELECT BB.StudentFirstName,BB.StudentLastName,
IFNULL(AA.ClassName,
CONCAT('All Classes for ',BB.StudentFirstName,' ',BB.StudentLastName)) ClassName,
IFNULL(AA.StudentAverage,0) StudentAverage FROM
students BB LEFT JOIN
(select A.StudentID,A.ClassName,avg(Grade) StudentAverage
from tests A inner join students B on A.StudentID=B.StudentID
group by A.StudentID,A.ClassName WITH ROLLUP) AA
on AA.StudentID=BB.StudentID;
```

## BONUS QUERY EXECUTED

```
mysql> SELECT BB.StudentFirstName,BB.StudentLastName,
    -> IFNULL(AA.ClassName,
    -> CONCAT('All Classes for ',BB.StudentFirstName,' ',BB.StudentLastName)) ClassName,
    -> IFNULL(AA.StudentAverage,0) StudentAverage FROM
    -> students BB LEFT JOIN
    -> (select A.StudentID,A.ClassName,avg(Grade) StudentAverage
    -> from tests A inner join students B on A.StudentID=B.StudentID
    -> group by A.StudentID,A.ClassName WITH ROLLUP) AA
    -> on AA.StudentID=BB.StudentID;
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
| StudentFirstName | StudentLastName | ClassName                       | StudentAverage |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
| agam             | rafaeli         | Algebra                         |        88.3333 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Algo                            |        97.0000 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Calcules                        |        86.0000 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Set-theory                      |        85.0000 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | All Classes for agam rafaeli    |        88.8333 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Algebra                         |        79.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Algo                            |        83.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Calcules                        |        89.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Set-theory                      |        84.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | All Classes for amir aizinger   |        83.7500 |
| avi              | caspi           | Algebra                         |        99.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Algo                            |        97.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Calcules                        |        96.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Set-theory                      |        95.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | All Classes for avi caspi       |        96.7500 |
| avia             | wolf            | All Classes for avia wolf       |        78.0000 |
| avia             | wolf            | Algebra                         |        78.0000 |
| ben              | moskovich       | All Classes for ben moskovich   |         0.0000 |
| chen             | segalovich      | All Classes for chen segalovich |         0.0000 |
| dana             | levy            | All Classes for dana levy       |         0.0000 |
| daniel           | marcus          | All Classes for daniel marcus   |         0.0000 |
| daphna           | chwarts         | All Classes for daphna chwarts  |         0.0000 |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+----------------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible, because you have different granularity in the two queries. You would have to calculate one average by yourself with a formula like `sum(grades) / count(distinct full-student-name)`. (btw, your use of `distinct` is not necessary, the `group by` does that already for you)
With this you would get the count correct, but you would sum too much grades, because they are multiplied by the grouping for classes. You can't do `sum(distinct grades)` because a student could have the same grade in different classes.
You also can't calculate the average of the averages. That's usually close, but still not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution using correlated sub-queries

```
SELECT   StudentFirstName,
         StudentLastName,
         ClassName,
         (SELECT Avg(Grade) FROM Tests WHERE ClassName = t.ClassName AND StudentId =s.StudentId) AS StudentClassAverage,
         (SELECT Avg(Grade) FROM Tests WHERE StudentId =s.StudentId) AS StudentAverage
FROM     Students s
         JOIN Tests t
             ON s.StudentId = t.StudentId
GROUP BY s.StudentId
```

## UPDATE 2017-12-05 11:20 EST from RolandoMySQLDBA

Based on Verace's comment, I did set the sql_mode to blank. Here is the output

```
mysql> SELECT   StudentFirstName,
    ->          StudentLastName,
    ->          ClassName,
    ->          (SELECT Avg(Grade) FROM Tests WHERE ClassName = t.ClassName AND StudentId =s.StudentId) AS StudentClassAverage,
    ->          (SELECT Avg(Grade) FROM Tests WHERE StudentId =s.StudentId) AS StudentAverage
    -> FROM     Students s
    ->          JOIN Tests t
    ->              ON s.StudentId = t.StudentId
    -> GROUP BY s.StudentId;
+------------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
| StudentFirstName | StudentLastName | ClassName  | StudentClassAverage | StudentAverage |
+------------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
| agam             | rafaeli         | Algebra    |             88.3333 |        88.8333 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Set-theory |             84.0000 |        83.7500 |
| avi              | caspi           | Algebra    |             99.0000 |        96.7500 |
| avia             | wolf            | Algebra    |             78.0000 |        78.0000 |
+------------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Although not all subjects appear for every student that took a test, the averages are correct for what was retrieved. The challenge here would be to adjust the query for the averages of every subject to appear. I am going to upvote this because correlated subqueries can be real headaches sometimes but can inevitably do the job.

Comment: That's not valid syntax `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: oops - edited...

Comment: This does not work in MySQL 5.7

Comment: It will if you set `sql_mode = ''`! :-) Do **NOT** do this at home, children...

Comment: @Vérace I tried it with `sql_mode=''`. I will post the output.