# Another way to write avg query

Tags: mysql

> Looking for another ways to write a query that finds for each student his average in each subject.

**Students table:**

```
  pk-INT           VARCHAR             VARCHAR
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| StudentID | StudentFirstName | StudentLastName |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
|         1 | agam             | rafaeli         |
|         2 | amir             | aizinger        |
|         3 | avi              | caspi           |
|         4 | avia             | wolf            |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

**Tests table:**

```
  PK-VARCHR    PK-VARCHR     PK&FK-INT   INT
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| TestDate   | ClassName  | StudentID | Grade |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2017-07-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    88 |
| 2017-08-02 | Algo       |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    80 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Set-theory |         1 |    85 |
| 2017-09-04 | Calcules   |         1 |    86 |
| 2016-05-03 | Set-theory |         2 |    84 |
| 2016-07-02 | Calcules   |         2 |    89 |
| 2016-07-04 | Algo       |         2 |    83 |
| 2016-07-05 | Algebra    |         2 |    79 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         3 |    99 |
| 2016-07-02 | Algo       |         3 |    97 |
| 2016-07-03 | Calcules   |         3 |    96 |
| 2016-09-03 | Set-theory |         3 |    95 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         4 |    78 |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

**Output:**

```
+------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| StudentFirstName | StudentLastName | ClassName  | AVG(Grade) |
+------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| agam             | rafaeli         | Algebra    |    88.3333 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Algo       |    97.0000 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Calcules   |    86.0000 |
| agam             | rafaeli         | Set-theory |    77.5000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Algebra    |    79.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Algo       |    83.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Calcules   |    89.0000 |
| amir             | aizinger        | Set-theory |    84.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Algebra    |    99.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Algo       |    97.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Calcules   |    96.0000 |
| avi              | caspi           | Set-theory |    95.0000 |
| avia             | wolf            | Algebra    |    78.0000 |
| avia             | wolf            | Algo       |    77.0000 |
| avia             | wolf            | Calcules   |    67.0000 |
| avia             | wolf            | Set-theory |    97.0000 |
+------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, ClassName, AVG(Grade) AS 'average for this subject'
FROM tests 
INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
GROUP BY StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,ClassName;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS error404;
CREATE DATABASE error404;
USE error404
CREATE TABLE students
(
    StudentID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    StudentFirstName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentLastName  VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);
INSERT INTO students (StudentFirstName,StudentLastName) VALUES
('agam'  , 'rafaeli'), ('amir'  , 'aizinger'), ('avi'   , 'caspi'),
('avia'  , 'wolf ');
CREATE TABLE tests
(
    testid    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TestDate  DATE,
    ClassName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    Grade     INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (testid),
    KEY (StudentID)
);
INSERT INTO tests (TestDate,ClassName,StudentID,Grade) VALUES
('2017-07-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 88 ), ('2017-08-02', 'Algo'       , 1 , 97 ),
('2017-09-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 80 ), ('2017-09-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 97 ),
('2017-09-01', 'Set-theory' , 1 , 85 ), ('2017-09-04', 'Calcules'   , 1 , 86 ),
('2016-05-03', 'Set-theory' , 2 , 84 ), ('2016-07-02', 'Calcules'   , 2 , 89 ),
('2016-07-04', 'Algo'       , 2 , 83 ), ('2016-07-05', 'Algebra'    , 2 , 79 ),
('2016-06-03', 'Algebra'    , 3 , 99 ), ('2016-07-02', 'Algo'       , 3 , 97 ),
('2016-07-03', 'Calcules'   , 3 , 96 ), ('2016-09-03', 'Set-theory' , 3 , 95 ),
('2016-06-03', 'Algebra'    , 4 , 78 );
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is about. Your query works as expected, right?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ , Yes, my query works as expected, I'm looking for another approaches for writing this query.

Comment: I hope my original answer helped you as well : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/192380/877

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Sure, Great answer!!! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, ClassName, avg_grade AS 'average for this subject'
FROM (SELECT StudentID, ClassName, AVG(Grade) AS avg_grade
      FROM tests 
      GROUP BY StudentID, ClassName) t
INNER JOIN students ON t.StudentID=students.StudentID
```

Horses for courses. Works pretty much the same as your method. I'd write it your way in this instance if I were me.

But it IS a good conceptual exercise to try to think of and compare different approaches like you're doing. Keep it up! :)

One thing to note: you should really reference the source table in the SELECT clause. To avoid ambiguity or future complications:

```
SELECT students.StudentFirstName, students.StudentLastName,
       t.ClassName, t.avg_grade AS 'average for this subject'
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your Grade field as Float or change the column type (best approach).

E.g.:
(AVG(CAST(Grade AS FLOAT))

Comment: this gives an error, I'm looking for more essential difference

Comment: Try without the first (..

Just: AVG(CAST(Grade AS FLOAT))

And if you want to round the decimals use ROUND(AVG(CAST(Grade AS FLOAT)), 3)